# Recursive addition in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, addition

The problem:

> You are given a function `plusOne x = x + 1`. Without using any other `(+)`s, define a recursive function `addition` such that `addition x y` adds `x` and `y` together.

(from [wikibooks.org](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Recursion#Other_recursive_functions))

My code (it does not work -- endless loop):

```
plusOne x = x + 1

addition x y 
  | x > 0  =  addition (plusOne y) (x-1)
  | otherwise = y
```

Questions:

1. How to connect the `plusOne` function to the `addition` recursive function?
2. How should it be written?

Comment: `y` is the value that is decreasing towards 0, not `x`.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up `x` and `y` in your recursive case

```
addition x y | y > 0 = addition (plusOne x) (y - 1)  -- x + y == (x + 1) + (y - 1)
             | otherwise = x   -- x + 0 = x
```

Answer (score 0):

using `==` and `0`

```
addition = add 0 where
    add a y x | a == y = x
              | otherwise = add (plusOne a) y (plusOne x)
```